# Can D-Link DIR-600 work in client mode?

Tags: networking, wireless-networking

Using default firmware I can't find anywhere option of changing mode to something other than access point. Can DIR-600 work in client mode with default or some other firmware? Are other modes available?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it most certainly can. I use a similar router with [DD-WRT](http://www.dd-wrt.com/), an open-source Linux-based router firmware. There are [instructions](http://www.dd-wrt.com/wiki/index.php/DIR-600) for installation on a DIR-600, and instructions for using it as a client (bridge) are [here](http://www.dd-wrt.com/wiki/index.php/Client_Bridged). Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

I was looking for same thing and JUST before installing 3rd party rom, i gave it a try and looked more in the router settings.
I found (to my surprise) there were options for WDS and WDS+AP+Router etc to select from in WIRELESS -> NETWORK SETTINGS of my D-Link DIR-600L router.

### Upon a little more googling i found that this router DOES support wds or wifi client mode by default.

I found [here](http://forums.dlink.com/index.php?topic=52818.0) the below instructions, were for using 2 same dlink routers and for model 605 but seems like will work nicely with this version too, and with a little understanding will work with any other router too, main thing is that it DOES have wds option in it.

=========================

With the help of D-Link tech support, I am able to get WDS working. Here are the steps.

1. Connect internet(WAN) cable to 1st router. Configure its wireless mode as "WDS + AP + Router".
2. On the 2nd router, disable DHCP server and configure router IP address as "192.168.0.2". Configure wireless mode as "WDS + AP"
3. Configure the same SSID, wireless security settings and wireless channel on both the routers.
4. In router 1, configure the router 2 mac address(from the backside of the router) in the Wireless Settings->Bridge Settings->Remote Mac address.
5. Similarly, configure the router 1 mac address in router 2->wireless Settings->Bridge Settings->Remote MAC address.

With the above step, WDS is working. I haven't tried configuring bridge security though.

=========================

I have not tried it because i didn't needed to, i was just messing around with an old piece of router. When i saw their is wds option available in it, i stopped further work.

And i am sure it will do, Enjoy.

**Also, just now, when i was sneaking around while writing this answer on a side, i got [this video](https://youtu.be/hGCgVEfI9bo) on youtube which is doing all this using only options which are available in our model and also in the model he is using in video... so now its certain this WILL work. Good luck.**

**PS:** upon my reset search on internet, it is possible that same model routers of D-Link MIGHT not have same options available worldwide, mine or yours might be a chinese clone or something, whatever it is possible that one router might have this option and other don't, although they are of same models... crazy, yeah i know. But it is possible, and you will need to use third party firmware is that is the case with you. Or perhaps, i can backup my firmware and share with you if you need. Let me know if this is the case i will try to do so. CHEERS.

Answer (score 0):

No, the D-Link 600 rev. C1 doesn't support client mode.

Comment: Any sources for that? The other answer claims it's possible.

Comment: Other answer uses an alternative firmware. Might be worth stressing that it is not possible with the default firmware but that the model may support DD-WRT.

Comment: I am looking for same thing and a little googling tells there MIGHT be something possible with factory firmware too. I will post an answer if i find one

Comment: see my answer here, i found it, it is possible with factory firmware.